# Deal with DC offset

Tags: arduino, dc, stm32, teensy

I have [STM32 BluePill](https://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Blue_Pill) and Teensy 3.2 , they both read analog 0 < x < 3.3V.

I want to read earphone microphone sound but the mic produce +-2.5V (with ~200mA, but this is a different problem).

Now my MCUs will "clip" every thing below to 0V and above 3.3V. Therefore I want to fix this DC offset in the input, so that the center will be 1.65V and my amplitude will be 1.65V (so I will have +- 1.65V signal, centered around 1.65V so in total I will use the entire 0 < x < 3.3V `analogRead()` range).

In the way out (`analogWrite()`) I guess I will have to change the offset again from 0 < x < 3.3V to -2.5V < 0 < 2.5V.

My questions are:

1. How can I change the DC offset from -2.5V < x < 2.5V (when x is 0) to 0 < x < 3.3V (when x is 1.65V)?
2. How can I change the DC offset back from 0 < x < 3.3V (when x is 1.65V) to -2.5V < x < 2.5V (when x is 0)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things, first attenuate the signal. It has amplitude of 5 V and you need to attenuate it so that it is less than
3.3 V. Then you have to change the offset.

This is a circuit that does just that.
[image]

R1 and R2 attenuate the signal. These resistor attenuate the 5 V signal amplitude quite accurately to 3.3 V. In reality you might want to attenuate it slightly more, to have some head room. So you might want to to use smaller R2 like 1.8k or something like that.

C1 blocks the DC component of the signal and R3 and R4 bias the signal to the middle of 3.3 V.

Due to high resistance of the resistors you can't load this circuit much. You might need to add an opamp as buffer to avoid the ADC from distorting the signal. Or if your microphone can provide enough current, you could just decrease the size of the resistors. Just don't change their ratios.

Comment: What is V1 ? and in the schema , in 3.3v I put the 3.3v of the bluepill, all grounds also from the bluepill, but where the mic + and mic ground fit in the schema?

Comment: V1 represents the microphone.

Comment: And What is `sine(0 2.5 100)` ? and `.tran 1`

Comment: oh, those are just the way LTSpice represents things. You can just ignore them. I was too lazy to clean them from the screenshot. "sine(0 2.5 100)" means that V1 is a sine wave source with 0 V offset, 2.5 V amplitude and 100 Hz frequency. The ".tran 1" is the simulation settings, transient simulation with 1 second stop time.

Comment: Thank you, last question (I think), I see where the grounds come in (every triangle is a ground), I see where the 3.3v power come in and I understand where the mic. is positioned, but from where I get the final output?

Comment: I updated the picture in the answer to have the output. I also changed the voltage source to microphone symbol. Though I'm not quite sure if that is the correct symbol. If anyone knows a better symbol, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, now i completely understand the picture

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a single supply ADC with the analog and digital ground tied together will automatically require a dc offset input. The best approach is to use an external op amp, that buffers the input and provides the dc offset, like this one below:

[image: schematic]

<sub>Image source: [Analog Devices - Circuit Note CN0336, Figure 2](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/hardware-reference-design/circuits-from-the-lab/CN0336.html)</sub>